# Best practice to disable all operations in google map for outside some area of polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

I want to mask outside a polygon in google map such that, the drawing manager allows drawing only in that polygon. I am using ng2-map in angular2.

```
<ng2-map [zoom]="mapOptions.zoom" [minZoom]="mapOptions.minZoom" [center]="mapOptions.center" (click)="mapClick($event)">
                    <drawing-manager *ngIf = "selectedJurisdictions.length > 0" 
                        [drawingMode]="'null'"
                        [drawingControl]="true"
                        [drawingControlOptions]="{
                          position: 2,
                          drawingModes: ['circle', 'polygon']
                         }"
                        [circleOptions]="{
                          fillColor: 'red',
                          fillOpacity: 0.3,
                          strokeColor: 'black',
                          strokeWeight: 2,
                          editable: true,
                          draggable: true,
                          zIndex: 1
                        }"
                        [polygonOptions]="{
                          fillColor: 'red',
                          fillOpacity: 0.3,
                          strokeColor: 'black',
                          strokeWeight: 2,
                          editable: true,
                          draggable: true,
                          zIndex: 1
                        }"
                        (polygoncomplete)="polygonCompleteFunction($event)"
                        (circlecomplete)="circleCompleteFunction($event)">
                    </drawing-manager>
                    <!--Begin Jurisdiction shapes-->
                    <map-polygon  *ngFor="let polygonData of jurisdictionPolygons" [editable]="false"
                        [paths]="polygonData"
                        [strokeColor]="mapJurisdictionOptions.strokeColor"
                        [strokeOpacity]="mapJurisdictionOptions.strokeOpacity"
                        [strokeWeight]="mapJurisdictionOptions.strokeWeight"
                        [fillColor]="mapJurisdictionOptions.fillColor"
                        [fillOpacity]="mapJurisdictionOptions.fillOpacity" zindex="2">
                    </map-polygon>
                    <map-circle  *ngFor="let circleData of jurisdictionCircles" 
                        [center]="circleData.geocode"
                        [strokeColor]="mapJurisdictionOptions.strokeColor"
                        [strokeOpacity]="mapJurisdictionOptions.strokeOpacity"
                        [strokeWeight]="mapJurisdictionOptions.strokeWeight"
                        [radius] ="circleData.radius"
                        [fillColor] = "mapJurisdictionOptions.fillColor" 
                        [fillOpacity]="mapJurisdictionOptions.fillOpacity"
                        draggable="false" [editable]="false" zindex="2">
                    </map-circle>
                    <!--End Jurisdiction shapes-->
                    <kml-layer url="http://localhost/kml_s.kml"></kml-layer>
                </ng2-map>
```

Comment: Any Luck on this part?

Comment: So far, I drew a polygon and added listeners onto that polygon this way the user is limited to draw only inside of that region.

Comment: Now, I want to give the user ability to drag and drop and edit the drawn shape but I want user should not take it outside of the region.

Comment: Add a polygon outside of that polygon ie the boundary will be the whole google map area except the selected polygon - fade with a color to indicate that is a drwaing disabled area. Actually user is able to draw in the outside area which you should restrict with the help of server side api - ie api will return tru or false by checking the drawn area polygon or circle is within the allowed area polygon. And on returning false alert the user and remove the drawn area.